# Flutter - trigger navigation when Provider variable changes

Tags: flutter, triggers, navigation, splash-screen, provider

I'm trying to show a splash screen on initial app startup until I have all of the data properly retrieved. The retrieval is done by a class called "ProductData" As soon as it's ready, I want to navigate from the splash page to the main screen of the app.

Unfortunately, I can't find a good way to trigger a method that runs that kind of Navigation and listens to a Provider.

This is the code that I'm using to test this idea. Specifically, I want to run the command Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home'); when the variable shouldProceed becomes true. Unfortunately, the code below gives me the error, "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build."

```
import 'package:catalogo/firebase/ProductData.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';=
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class RouteSplash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RouteSplashState createState() => _RouteSplashState();
}

class _RouteSplashState extends State<RouteSplash> {
  bool shouldProceed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    shouldProceed =
        Provider.of<ProductData>(context, listen: true).shouldProceed; 
    if (shouldProceed) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home'); <-- The error occurs when this line is hit.
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to navigate to a page based on listening to the results of a provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to navigate to a new view what you should do is display the loading splash screen if you are still waiting for data and once that changes display your main home view, like this:

```
import 'package:catalogo/firebase/ProductData.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  bool shouldProceed = Provider.of<ProductData>(context, listen: true).shouldProceed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(shouldProceed){
      return Home();
    }else{
      return RouteSplash();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this approach a couple of times now. What bugs me is that since there is no Navigator involved in this scenario, there are no visuals for the screen transitions. The new screen simply pops up all of a sudden. Is this take-it-or-leave-it, or can it be improved?

Comment: Well, you could use the `Navigator`, but that would force you to remove that `RouteSplash` from the `Navigator` stack, because you don't want your user to be able to navigate back to the splash screen.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as described above: I'm getting "setState or markNeedsBuild called during state" when trying to push a new screen triggered by a state-change from my BLoC. The only way I found was to use a ```GlobalKey``` to access the ```Navigator``` state without the usually necessary ```BuildContext``` and push directly from within the BLoC. For me this is also not really clean. In my opinion navigation should stay in the UI part of the application. Is there another way?

Comment: Stumbled across this today: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/201... Unfortunately the vast amount of Counter tutorials for BLoC made it really hard to find the stuff that really matters. Thanks for making me keep looking!

Answer (score 3):

Anyone else facing this issue can use this code

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => Navigate.toView(context));
```

This navigates to the other screen without build errors

Comment: hackerman. love it

Answer (score 2):

Use BlocListener as in this example:

```
BlocListener(
    bloc: BlocProvider.of<DataBloc>(context),
    listener: (BuildContext context, DataState state) {
        if (state is Success) {              
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/details');
        }              
    },
    child: BlocBuilder(
        bloc: BlocProvider.of<DataBloc>(context),
        builder: (BuildContext context, DataState state) {        
            if (state is Initial) {
                return Text('Press the Button');
            }
            if (state is Loading) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }  
            if (state is Success) {
                return Text('Success');
            }  
            if (state is Failure) {
                return Text('Failure');
            }
        },
    }
)
```

Source: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/201

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution that does what the OP wants.  If you make your splash screen to be `Stateful`, then you can add a `PostFrameCallback`.  This avoids any problems with `Navigator` being called when `build` is running.  Your callback can then call whatever routine `Provider` needs to read the data.  This read data routine can be passed a further callback which contains the `Navigator` command.

In my solution I've added a further callback so that the splash screen is visible for at least one second (you can choose what duration you think reasonable here).  Unfortunately, this creates a race condition, so I need to import the `synchronized` package to avoid problems.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reflect/utils/constants.dart';
import 'category_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:reflect/data_models/app_prefs.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:synchronized/synchronized.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = 'LoadingScreen';

  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  bool readPrefsDone = false;
  bool timeFinished = false;
  Lock _lock = Lock();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Provider.of<AppPrefs>(context, listen: false).readPrefs(readDone);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        timerDone();
      });
    });
  }

  void timerDone() async {
    _lock.synchronized(() {
      if (readPrefsDone) {
        pushMainScreen();
      }
      timeFinished = true;
    });
  }

  void readDone() {
    _lock.synchronized(() {
      if (timeFinished) {
        pushMainScreen();
      }
      readPrefsDone = true;
    });
  }

  void pushMainScreen() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation, animation2) => CategoryScreen(),
        transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Hero(
              tag: kFishLogoTag,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/fish_logo.png'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Text(
              'Reflect',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                color: Color(0xFF0000cc),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```